# Customer password update on migration from old site Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Customer password update on migration from old site

I am migrating from an old site and have over 6000 customers.  Passwords for their online accounts cannot be imported so I would like to ensure that they are forced to select/change their password on first login.  All I can see is a way to do that one at a time through the dashboard.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this can only be enabled through your control panel, and not a CSV export/import. Changing this functionality to allow it to occur in bulk is scheduled for a future release, though!

Here is more information on forcing customers to reset their passwords:

https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Customer-Account-Management/#pw-reset

Alternatively, you could send out an email blast through your store's dedicated email system to all of your customers letting them know to reset their passwords, saying something like, "Due to changes in our system, you password will need to be reset. Go to [www.domain.com/login.php?action=reset_password](http://www.domain.com/login.php?action=reset_password) to reset your password now."